# XSL not working and I can't troubleshoot why

Tags: xml, xslt

I am literally copy-pasting the tutorial on https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_transformation.asp yet when opening my own cdcatalog.xml from my browser it displays as plain text instead of nicely formatted like the example in w3schools. I don't know what to do. Here is my code

file: cdcatalog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="cdcatalog.xsl"?>
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>CBS Records</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1988</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Greatest Hits</title>
    <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>RCA</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1982</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Still got the blues</title>
    <artist>Gary Moore</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>Virgin records</company>
    <price>10.20</price>
    <year>1990</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Eros</title>
    <artist>Eros Ramazzotti</artist>
    <country>EU</country>
    <company>BMG</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1997</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>One night only</title>
    <artist>Bee Gees</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>Polydor</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1998</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Sylvias Mother</title>
    <artist>Dr.Hook</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>CBS</company>
    <price>8.10</price>
    <year>1973</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Maggie May</title>
    <artist>Rod Stewart</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>Pickwick</company>
    <price>8.50</price>
    <year>1990</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Romanza</title>
    <artist>Andrea Bocelli</artist>
    <country>EU</country>
    <company>Polydor</company>
    <price>10.80</price>
    <year>1996</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>When a man loves a woman</title>
    <artist>Percy Sledge</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Atlantic</company>
    <price>8.70</price>
    <year>1987</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Black angel</title>
    <artist>Savage Rose</artist>
    <country>EU</country>
    <company>Mega</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1995</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>1999 Grammy Nominees</title>
    <artist>Many</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Grammy</company>
    <price>10.20</price>
    <year>1999</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>For the good times</title>
    <artist>Kenny Rogers</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>Mucik Master</company>
    <price>8.70</price>
    <year>1995</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Big Willie style</title>
    <artist>Will Smith</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1997</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Tupelo Honey</title>
    <artist>Van Morrison</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>Polydor</company>
    <price>8.20</price>
    <year>1971</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Soulsville</title>
    <artist>Jorn Hoel</artist>
    <country>Norway</country>
    <company>WEA</company>
    <price>7.90</price>
    <year>1996</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>The very best of</title>
    <artist>Cat Stevens</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>Island</company>
    <price>8.90</price>
    <year>1990</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Stop</title>
    <artist>Sam Brown</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>A and M</company>
    <price>8.90</price>
    <year>1988</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Bridge of Spies</title>
    <artist>T`Pau</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>Siren</company>
    <price>7.90</price>
    <year>1987</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Private Dancer</title>
    <artist>Tina Turner</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>Capitol</company>
    <price>8.90</price>
    <year>1983</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Midt om natten</title>
    <artist>Kim Larsen</artist>
    <country>EU</country>
    <company>Medley</company>
    <price>7.80</price>
    <year>1983</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Pavarotti Gala Concert</title>
    <artist>Luciano Pavarotti</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>DECCA</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1991</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>The dock of the bay</title>
    <artist>Otis Redding</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <COMPANY>Stax Records</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>7.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1968</YEAR>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Picture book</title>
    <artist>Simply Red</artist>
    <country>EU</country>
    <company>Elektra</company>
    <price>7.20</price>
    <year>1985</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Red</title>
    <artist>The Communards</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>London</company>
    <price>7.80</price>
    <year>1987</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Unchain my heart</title>
    <artist>Joe Cocker</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>EMI</company>
    <price>8.20</price>
    <year>1987</year>
  </cd>
</catalog>
```

file: cdcatalog.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html> 
<body>
  <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th style="text-align:left">Title</th>
      <th style="text-align:left">Artist</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your browser has a console you can usually open with F12, so do that and I am sure you will find warning or error, I guess, due to the unsupported attempt to load your XSLT from the local file system.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thank you man, I am using firefox. It says Cross-Origin Request Blocked. Guess I'll have to look into it

Comment: Most browsers these days won't allow loading a stylesheet from local file store, it has to be from a HTTP server.